# ASP.net - Center Align Panel?

Tags: asp.net, html, alignment, panel, center

I need to center align a panel. I use the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestDefault.aspx.cs" Inherits="tregware.TestDefault" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="Root" runat="server" BackColor="Red"  HorizontalAlign="Center" Style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 0;">


<asp:Panel ID="Body" runat="server" BackColor="Blue" 
    Style="left: 0px; top: 24px;width: 800px; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 0;" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center">
</asp:Panel>

</asp:Panel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However the panel ("Body") will not center. How would I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set `position: absolute`, so a lot of the regular methods you would use to center elements probably won't work.

Since you've set a fixed `width` of `800px`, you could use:

```
Style="left: 50%; margin-left: -400px; ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Panel has the property of **HorizontalAlign**

```
<asp:Panel id="reqId" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" >
Your Text Here
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css called `.panel { align:center }`

and then add it to the panel `CssClass = "panel"`